# How to get Id of an element using jQuery Closest() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

i have following HTML struture, I am unable to get the value of a radio button when i select my selector as explained in my Jquery Code Below.

```
<div class="option-radio-box">
<input id="pixel" class="css-checkbox" type="radio" value="pixel" name="type">
<label class="css-label" for="radio1">
<img width="25" height="20" alt="" src="images/opt-ico1.png">
Pixel by
<span>Pixel</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="option-radio-box">
<input id="pair" class="css-checkbox" type="radio" checked="checked" value="pair" name="type">
<label class="css-label" for="radio2">
<img width="25" height="20" alt="" src="images/opt-ico2.png">
Duplicate
<span>Search</span>
</label>
</div>
```

And following Jquery code,

```
  $('.css-label').on('click', function() {
  alert(jQuery(this).closest('input:radio[name=type]').id);});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff:`jQuery(this).closest('input:radio[name=type]').attr('id'));` already tried this i am getting empty alert

Comment: Ya because it is not an ancestor of this element, see @adeneo's answer, and upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radio button is not a parent, but a sibling, and a jQuery object has no `.id` property

```
$('.css-label').on('click', function() {
      alert( $(this).siblings('input:radio[name=type]').prop('id') );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aW8nN/)

Comment: Thanks that what i wanted(10 minute timer to wait to accept answer), Btw i didnt placed parent here, so closest looks for parent elements?

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` searches the element's ancestors, whereas the `input` element is a sibling in your HTML. You can do something like this:

```
$('.css-label').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).siblings('input[name="type"]:checked').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/2gZzd/3/)**

```
$('.css-label').on('click', function() {
    parentElement = jQuery(this).parents('.option-radio-box');
alert($("input[type='radio']",parentElement).attr("id"));  
});
```